# explicit method of templates for functions of non void return in c++

Tags: c++, function, templates, instantiation, explicit

I wish to write a function template to find larger of the two numbers passed in as parameters. And I want to explicitly instantiate this function template for `int`.

So I wrote in the larger.h the following;

```
template <typename T>
const T& larger(T a,T b);
```

I wrote in larger.cpp the following:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"larger.h"
const T& larger(T a,T b) {
    return a<b?b:a;
}
```

In the main.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "larger.h"
int main(){
    template int()
    const& larger<int>(int,int);
    std::cout << larger(6,8) << std::endl;
}
```

When I compile and try to run main.cpp,I get the following error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘template’
 template int()
```

I am unable to proceed further. What's wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with [std::max](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max)? It already exists and does exactly what you want.

Comment: What is `template int()` supposed to be?

Answer (score 4):

Problems I see:

1. `template`s need to be implemented in header files, not source files. See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).
2. The syntax for declaring an explicit specialization of `larger` for `int` is:

   ```
   template <> int const& larger<int>(int,int);
   ```

   That is different than the syntax for explicit instantiation of `larger` for `int`. That will be:

   ```
   template int const& larger<int>(int,int);
   ```

   It's not clear from your post which one you want.
3. The declaration must be outside a function, not inside.

   ```
   template <> int const& larger<int>(int,int);

   int main()
   {
      std::cout<<larger(6,8)<<std::endl;
      return 0;
   }
   ```
4. `larger` returns a reference to a temporary. Change it to return a value

   ```
   template <typename T>
   T larger(T a,T b);
   ```

   or change the arguments to be of type `T const&`.

   ```
   template <typename T>
   T const& larger(T const& a, T const& b);
   ```

Comment: @RSahu "The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (6.6.3) is not
extended; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the return statement."

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @Barry.

Comment: No problem. Those rules are really complicated... easy to get confused in the mess.

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with your code.

1. Your `larger` is returning a reference to a temporary. You probably want to take your arguments by reference as well:

   ```
   template <typename T>
   T const& larger(T const&, T const& );
   ```
2. The syntax for explicitly instantiating a function template is:

   ```
   template int const& larger<int>(int const&, int const&);
   ```

   and it cannot be within the body of a function.
3. Explicit instantiations require the definition to be visible, so it can't be in `main.cpp`, it must go in `larger.cpp`. That is:

   ```
   #include"larger.h"

   const T& larger(T const& a,T const& b) {
       return a<b?b:a;
   }

   // must go here
   template int const& larger<int>(int const&, int const&);
   ```
4. Use [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max).